# integer index with loc[] in hierarchical indexing possible?

Tags: pandas

I thought .loc[] only allows label or boolean indexing, but in this code, integer index is used in .loc[] in hierarchical indexed series (data.loc[:, 2]) Is this only possible in hierarchical indexed series/dataframe or because the integer index is specified in the constructor?

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(9), index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], [1,2,3,1,3,1,2,2,3]])

    a  1   -0.204708
       2    0.478943
       3   -0.519439
    b  1   -0.555730
       3    1.965781
    c  1    1.393406
       2    0.092908
    d  2    0.281746
       3    0.769023

data.loc[:, 2]

    a    0.478943
    c    0.092908
    d    0.281746
    dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the documentation:

```
Series.loc
Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

.loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array.

Allowed inputs are:

A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
```

In your example 2 is interpreted as index label not the position.
You can do the same for not hierarchical indexed series:

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(9))
data.loc[2]
```